# VB .net question on a type of parameter such as ( Of type )

Tags: .net, vb.net

One of the methods in a object I am using on VB .net has a parameter similar to below

```
ByVal RepCollection as MyAppCollection(Of InvoiceReport )
```

Could someone help me understand  the technology behind this parameter type please ?

Comment: That means that `MyAppCollection` is a generic type, so you should do some reading on generics and generic types.  The most commonly used generic type is `List(Of T)`.  As an example, the `Item` property of a `List(Of T)` is type `T`, so you can only put that type in and you always get that type out.  If you create a `List(Of String)` then the `Item` property becomes type `String` and if you create a `List(Of Integer)` then `Item` is type `Integer`.  Etc.

Comment: This is a syntax for declaring generic types, feature were introduced in .NET 2.0. [Generic Types in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyAppCollection(Of T)` is a **generic** collection type. To use the type, you must declare it with a more specific `T` value, such as `InvoiceReport`. When you do this, you create a collection that can only hold `InvoiceReport` objects and doesn't require any casting or boxing, even with `Option Strict` turned on. You only have to implement one collection type, but you can use it with any kind of object, and you still get full type safety and checking. It's been part of the VB language for more than 10 years now.